# how to get user details by user id in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I am using Firebase Realtime database.
I have created UserDetails table In that table I have saved no.of user registered details with userId.
Now I want to fetch that deatails for given userId.

How can I do that in firebase?

Is there any function provided by Firebase or Is there any way to apply query on that table.

Comment: Please share your code . Without code no one will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code for query

```
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        mFirebaseInstance.goOnline();
                        DatabaseReference ref = mFirebaseInstance.getReference(<Root KEY>);

                        Query applyQuery = ref.child(<NESTED KEY IF ANY>)
                                .child("<CHILD TAG, IN YOUR CASE USER ID>").
                                        orderByChild("<CHILD ID TAG>").equalTo("your id");

                        applyQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot removeAppSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    // Perform Task
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Log.e("Realtime", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                            }
                        });
```